# How to handle Firestore Query Results for later usage

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, google-cloud-firestore

I am currently struggling with my Firestore query results.
What I want to do is to query the database, fetch the results, write the result in an array --> this is already working with my code below!
But in addition to this I need that array later to compare it to a different array from a second query and this is where the issue is.

```
var arrayOfTuples = [(Int, String)]()

db.collection("Data").whereField("age", isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: 1).whereField("age", isLessThanOrEqualTo: 50).whereField("gender", isEqualTo: "F").getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in
    if let err = err {
        print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
    } else {
             for (index, document) in querySnapshot!.documents.enumerated() {
             arrayOfTuples += [(index, document.documentID)]
             }       
    }
    print(arrayOfTuples)
} 
//Place where I need the array result
```

I can use the array result in the last print method, but I need it out of the last bracket that I can compare it to the second query result.
Have not found anything that I could return the result, but maybe it's completely simple (hope so).

Hope it's clear, otherwise just let me know.
Thanks!

Comment: I think this tutorial could be useful for you https://medium.com/@vladfr/use-cloud-firestore-with-async-bce875af0183

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't make an asynchronous call synchronous  you need

```
func loadQuery(com:@escaping( [(Int, String)] -> ())){ 
    var arrayOfTuples = [(Int, String)]() 
    db.collection("Data").whereField("age", isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: 1).whereField("age", isLessThanOrEqualTo: 50).whereField("gender", isEqualTo: "F").getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in
        if let err = err {
            print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
        } else {
                 for (index, document) in querySnapshot!.documents.enumerated() {
                 arrayOfTuples += [(index, document.documentID)]
                 }       
        }
        com(arrayOfTuples)
    } 
}
```

---

```
loadQuery { arr in 
  // compare here 
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's working! But I just understand it partially to be honest.
How should I compare two nearly similar functions like that in 
`
loadQuery { arr in 
  // compare here 
}
`
Because I have to convert the result to a **Set** in the next step to compare them with the intersection method.
Didn't wrote that above, sorry!